# Hyper-v. При установки Linux Server не виден диск

Tags: linux, hyper-v

Всем доброго времени суток!

Устанавливаю Linux Server 15.10 x64. Установка проходит нормально до шага "Определение дисков". На этом шаге предлагается выбрать драйвер или выйти в программу контроля iSCSI.

В чем может быть проблема или куда хоть копать?

Comment: А как расшарен винт в самом гиперв? В виртуалбоксе можно сделать или scsi или sata или ide. Можно даже sas.

Answer (score 1):

Linux не видит диски IDE размером больше 127 GB.
Зато SCSI -диски ограничена размером 2 TB.

Есть workaround:
Подключить несколько IDE -дисков по 127GB и объединить их в LVM на стороне linux.

Либо использовать только SCSI.

Answer (score 0):

Ха! Дело оказалось еще проще, чем разница в интерфейсах: по-умолчанию диск создался на 127 Гб,и где-то в недрах инета я нашел, что Linux под виртуалкой не видит диски размером 127 и более.

Comment: Всё прекрасно видит linux. hyper-v кластер, много linux-машин, в том числе с дисками более 500 GB

Comment: А интерфейс hdd какой?

Comment: ide, SCSI. Centos 6, 7